# Как можно осуществить поиск по элементам коллекции?

Tags: jquery

Есть коллекция элементов, сохраненная в переменную:

```
collect = jQuery('.class');
```

Можно ли как-то средствами `jQuery` отобрать "подколлекцию" по определенному селектору? Метод `find()` здесь не подходит, так как ищет элементы внутри элементов коллекции. Необходим поиск именно между самими элементами коллекции.

Comment: А можно пример `dom` элементов, что есть и что вы хотите найти?

Comment: Да, вопрос является дубликатом. Спасибо, по ссылке ответ на мой вопрос.